Book (maybe first in series) about a teenage assassin who's seeking revenge for his parents
I read this somewhere in the last 12 years or so, probably closer to 8-12 years ago based on my scant memories of circumstances (namely that I was reading it while waiting for the bus nearby my current house). I'm pretty sure it was an ebook that I got through the library. The protagonist is a teenage boy who is an assassin for an organization. In his past, he came home to find his parents brutally murdered and he was approached by the organization, who promised to help him train to avenge the death of his parents and, in exchange, he would work for them as an assassin while they tracked down the killers of his parents. I want to say that he was already blooded (had killed at least one target) at the beginning of the book, where he was assigned to infiltrate an embassy (I think... that's the word that comes to mind) to kill someone. I want to say that he'd undergone some process to reduce his emotional affect with the aim of making him a better killer.
In the course of the infiltration of the embassy, he meets a girl his age and she begins to break through his emotional shell. She might have been the daughter of his target? But as it is, he feels his emotional training crack and starts to care about other people. Eventually, this leads to the other fairly predictable plot point, that the shadowy agency that sends him out to kill people were behind the death of his parents. I don't recall whether his parents were killed entirely to make a killer out of him, or the organization just decided to make use of the situation.
I remember there only being a handful of incidents of violence in the book. I can't recall how detailed those incidents were. No sex as I recall it, probably just as well given the age of the protagonist and his potential love interests. I remember being a bit disappointed that they'd set up this trained teen assassin, but that his actual ability seemed rather unimpressive.

the shadowy agency that sends him out to kill people were behind the death of his parents. I called it as soon as I read he came home to find his parents brutally murdered and he was approached by the organization. I feel like I have read something like this in one of my friend's books but it will take a while for me to find it. Bear with me.

Boy Nobody by Allen Zadoff !! It fits your description almost perfectly I’m sure it’s the book your thinking of!

They needed the perfect assassin.
Boy Nobody is the perennial new kid in school, the one few notice and nobody thinks much about. He shows up in a new high school in a new town under a new name, makes a few friends, and doesn't stay long. Just long enough for someone in his new friend's family to die-of "natural causes." Mission accomplished, Boy Nobody disappears, moving on to the next target.
But when he's assigned to the mayor of New York City, things change. The daughter is unlike anyone he has encountered before; the mayor reminds him of his father. And when memories and questions surface, his handlers at The Program are watching. Because somewhere deep inside, Boy Nobody is somebody: the kid he once was; the teen who wants normal things, like a real home and parents; a young man who wants out. And who just might want those things badly enough to sabotage The Program's mission.

And from this review:

Our unnamed MC is known in the main arc of the story as "Benjamin." We are not given an entire back history of his past, but we do get glimpses of it in flashbacks. When he was twelve years old, his parents were killed by the Program, and he became initiated into it.

"Whatever I decided, my life was no longer my own. I could give it up forever and join my parents, or I could join The Program.
Twelve years old, and I had to make a choice between life and death.
I chose death.
Ironically, it was what they were looking for. It showed them the level of character they were seeking, the list of personality characteristics appropriate to a potential soldier.
Intensity.
Black-or-white thinking.
Stubbornness.
Allegiance without regard to consequence.
They took my allegiance and transformed it into something that would serve them."

He is seemingly stripped of personality, adapting it to the situation as it fits. He observes a new environment first, assesses the mark and like a skilled spy, selects the best method and personality to adapt in order to infiltrate his target. We're not meant to love him, Ben is a highly trained killer. He has killed before, we watch him kill not even 10 pages into the book. He does so again and again, methodically, instinctively, but never maliciously or needlessly. He is a soldier, it is his job. Ben does the same with this situation, but the daughter of the new mark turns out to be someone unexpected. Ben is successful at getting close to the target...but to his shock, to his bewilderment, he just can't bring himself to kill his target.


That very much looks like a match. Thanks! Was it one that you'd read before?

Wow, this is very similar to the bourne movie series and the hitman games (Matches hitman absolution more closely). I didn't realize this plot was quite common.
